# Folder browsing dialog for file download in Java

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I make an ajax call to a java servlet for download a xml file on client. I use this code for append a form on "success" ajax call and I force trigger for effective start file download.

My issue is that i would like to permit client user to choose where save the file and not download it in default browser folder.

Can I do that?

My client code is:

```
  function downloadAnnotationXML()
        {
           downloadAnnotation=true;
           var temp=new Object();
           temp.topic=topic;
           temp.operation=operation
           temp.data=annotazioniXml;
           var json = JSON.stringify(temp);
           var url="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/DownloadAnnotationServlet";
           $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {json:json},
            success: function(response, status, request) {
                var disp = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
                if (disp && disp.search('attachment') != -1) {
                    var form = $('<form id="ajax" method="POST" action="' + url + '">');
                   form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="json" value="json">'));

                    $('body').append(form);
                    form.submit();
                }
            },
            error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, thrownError ) 
             {
                error = "Non è stato possibile caricare l'oggetto";         
                msg = textStatus + thrownError;
                promptError(error+" <br /> "+ msg);         
            }
          });
        }
```

My java servlet code for header is :

```
   response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+file.getName());

                OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();
```

All work well but file is downloaded on default browser folder. :(

Answer (score 0):

The browser determines this. If their browser lets them save anywhere, it gives them a dialog. If their browser doesn't (like typically on a mobile device), it saves in a default location. You can't do anything about it.

If you're testing this on a modern browser like Firefox, go to you settings. Firefox's settings under the general tab has two options "Always ask where to save file" and "Save files to ..." some specific folder.  It is right for users to control this from their browser settings rather than each website controlling it, which is why this is a browser decision.

Comment: Yes I Know That! But I can't handle browser client settings. So I wish like to know a workaround to do That. As intercept response in dialog jquery for choose where save file.